# Can't see deployed asp.net mvc3 project on IIS7

Tags: iis, hostheader

I deployed my asp.net mvc3 project on IIS7 in my computer. Everything is ok here and when I browse localhost in browser or run app in visual studui 2010 I can see my project, but in other computer when I searched localhost, I can't see it. 
I did this to deploy app on IIS7:

1. install IIS7
2. create my projec in visual studio 2010
3. in IIS7 manager in Default Web Site section created a new app named tile-shop2 with ASP.NET V4.0 Application pool, and Physical path is the in wwwroot in inetpub
4. publish project in wwwroot folder
5. in VS2010 in Project menu => tile-shop2 properties => Web => Servers => ticked Use Local IIS Web server

What else should I do to see project on other computers? and can I see it in both windows and mac?

Comment: localhost means current computer. So localhost from other computer would reach out to that computer. You need to access the website either using host-header or the IP address of the computer on which website is installed. E.g. `http://<ip address>/<web site name>`

Comment: Do you mean I should find ip address of my computer in local network and type http://<ip address>/<web site name> in browser in other computer?

Comment: That is right Taban. But a host-header based solution would be better from production point of view. This article explains what is host-header http://www.it-notebook.org/iis/article/understanding_host_headers.htm

Comment: Thanks Suhas, could you please write this comment as answer and I'll mark it. I'll read that article and if face problem I'll write my question. IS reading that article enough for me?

Comment: I have added both the comments as answer. I think that article should give you enough knowledge of what host-headers are. Then it would not be difficult to find out how to use host-headers with IIS. If you face any challenges then let me know and I would help you with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

localhost means current computer. So localhost from other computer would reach out to that computer. You need to access the website either using host-header or the IP address of the computer on which website is installed. E.g. http:///

But a host-header based solution would be better from production point of view. This article explains what is host-header it-notebook.org/iis/article/understanding_host_headers.htm